# With Slop, how can I get both options and the arguments at the end?

Tags: ruby

I'm using [Slop](https://github.com/leejarvis/slop) for command-line argument parsing. I know from reading the documentation how to retrieve options:

```
opts = Slop.parse do
  on 'name=', 'Your name'
  on 'p', 'password', 'An optional password', argument: :optional
  on 'v', 'verbose', 'Enable verbose mode'
end
```

... and how to retrieve the final arguments ...

```
opts = Slop.parse! do
  on :foo
end
```

but not how to do both at the same time. I took a look through the unit tests and tried a few things, but I'm fairly new to Ruby and not sure how to specify the arguments correctly. Here's the method signature for Slop.parse! (thanks to @engineersmnky)

```
def parse!(items = ARGV, config = {}, &block)
```

I tried:

```
items = []
options = Slop.parse!(optional_arguments: true) do |x|
  on :d, :debug, "Print debug messages"
  items << x
end
```

.. but I get the following error:

```
undefined method `on' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ConfigurationProvider_2:0x007fcd4a83d550>
 # ./spec/configuration_provider_spec.rb:18:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ... and so on ...
```

Any insight would be welcome.

Comment: I am commenting simply because the signature is wrong `parse!` actually reads `def parse!(items=ARGV,config={},&block)` and then interchanges `items` and `config` if `items` is presented as a `Hash` using parallel assignment. Other than that I cannot really be of assistance.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question with your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! In retrospect, the documentation stating that `parse!` strips out the handled arguments contained the answer.

```
options = Slop.parse! do
    on :d, :debug, "Print debug messages"
end
remaining_args = ARGV
```

When I run this with "`prog.rb --debug 12345`", options = `{:debug => true}` and remaining_args = `[12345]`

Comment: I created a pull request to update Slop's documentation.

Comment: In the latest version of Slop as of 2017/05/26 (4.x), `Slop.parse!` no longer exists. Now you use `opts = Slop.parse ...`; `opts.arguments` to get the remaining arguments.